# Nested and recursive procedures in MIPS language

Tags: c++, c, mips

F and G are two procedures are defined as follows (in pseudo-language high
level):

```
int G(int n) {
int b = 0;
int u = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
    u = F(k);
    b = (b*b)+u;
}   
return b;
}

int F(int m) {
    if(m == 0) {
       return 1; 
    } 
    else {
       int p = F(m-1);
       return (2*p)+m;
    }
 }

 System.out.println(G(n));     //where n is a natural number
```

Using QtSpim, write and test a program that reads a first natural number n, and displays on the console:

- the value returned by the procedure G (n), implementing G and F as described
  previously. The calls to the two procedures G and F must be realized using the instruction jal (jump and link)
- the track with the sequence of nested calls (with argument between
  parenthesis) and the values returned by the various nested calls (return value between parentheses), for both G and for F

Example console output in the case where n = 1:

- Result: G (1) = 4
- Track: G (1) -> F (0) -> F-return (1) -> F (1) -> F (0) -> F-return (1) -> F-return (3) - > G-return (4)

Is there anyone who can help me translate this C/C++ code in MIPS language?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I wanted to know if anyone could help me translate that C/C++ language in MIPS language, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a little change that 'pseudo language high level' code is plain C(89). You have to change the order of F and G or add a forward declaration. BTW, only F is recursive and there is no nesting whatsoever. G just calls F.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int F(int m)
{
  if(m == 0) {
    return 1; 
  } 
  else {
    int p = F(m-1);
    return (2*p)+m;
  }
}

int G(int n)
{
  int b = 0;
  int u = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
    u = F(k);
    b = (b*b)+u;
  }   
  return b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%u\n", G(2));
  return 0;
}
```

Once in C, you can call gcc to compile it for MIPS (you can pick the processor or the name of a generic ISA):

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -march='mips3' -S -c filename.c
```

And you have an definitive compilation of your code to MIPS. Of course, if this was homework getting gcc doing the work for you would probably count as cheating.

Comment: This is a really funny answer :D